# How to determine an immediate constituent of a sentence

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, spanish, ambiguity, constituents

I am studying Spanish and Portuguese at university, and I am having some trouble with part of a Spanish linguistics assignment. I would be very grateful if somebody could shed some light on how to tackle this question :

Mi hermana me ha traído un mapa *de Madrid*

Show by means of tests whether the italicised strings are constituents. b) If the italicised strings prove to be constituents, state their syntactic function. c) In cases of structural ambiguity, state in words what the different interpretations might be. d)Then indicate the constituent structure with either labelled brackets or trees for each interpretation.

N.B. the linguistic tests to be used are reduction, ommission, substitution, movement and 'answer to a question'

Comment: Sorry, homework questions are off-topic here, see [help centre](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help) for more details.

Comment: What's your question, by the way? You've got the tests, as far as I understand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a do-my-homework.

Comment: I disagree that this is a do-my-homework. She asks how to approach the question, which is fine. Names of tests are different from understanding why tests show what they do, and my diagnosis is that she doesn't completely understand the logic of the tests. Obviously, we won't provide the actual homework answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first step, I suppose, is to re-state what fact about "answer to a question" refers to constituency (and likewise the other tests). Look at any other two-word sequence, like *hermana me*, *traido un*, *mapa de* and so on, and see if that fact holds. For some of these word pairs, that relationship does not hold. Questions about "syntactic function" would have to refer to whatever theory of syntactic function your instruction subscribes to. Identifying ambiguities is a native-like speaker magic skill, and sometimes people just can see the other interpretation(s), probably because the alternative interpretation seems silly (e.g. the ambiguity of "he sold a ticket to my boss").

Comment: The answer fragment test identifies phrasal constituents only. It does not identify subphrasal constituents. In fact most tests for constituents identify phrasal constituents only, not subphrasal ones too -- coordination is the one exception here. This is a major problem with tests for constituents that is overlooked by almost all textbooks on syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want extra credit, you might mention some cases where the tests you are supposed to use give incorrect results, depending of course on how your teacher reacts to criticism.  For instance, in "A scoop of ice cream is delicious with chocolate sauce -- it is called a sundae", evidently "it" is substituted for "a scoop of ice cream ... with chocolate sauce", but the latter is clearly not an immediate constituent.

Comment: The tests in general give incorrect results for subphrasal constituents l -- coordination is the one exception here. The majority of tests for constituents (topiclization, clefting, pseudoclefting, omission, proform substitution, answer fragments, etc.) cannot identify subphrasal strings as constituents. This aspect of the tests is ignored or overlooked by almost all textbooks on syntax.